# Laravel Dusk not running behing proxy

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-webdriver, laravel-dusk

#### Overview of the problem

I am trying to get started with Laravel Dusk, however, I cannot get it to run correctly. Based on the feedback from when I run it in the console and [some google searches](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Facebook%5CWebDriver%5CException%5CWebDriverException%3A%20JSON%20decoding%20of%20remote%20response%20failed&oq=Facebook%5CWebDriver%5CException%5CWebDriverException%3A%20JSON%20decoding%20of%20remote%20response%20failed&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1424j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=set%20proxy%20Facebook%5CWebDriver&*) and [the fact I'd experienced the same issues with a similar package](https://github.com/Modelizer/Laravel-Selenium/issues/15) before Dusk was released I am guessing the issue is down to being behind a proxy at my work-place. I could of course be wrong about it being about the proxy but it's the only thing I have to go on for now. If I'm honest I don't even understand why it needs to know my proxy settings for running local tests locally?

#### Set up

- Windows 7 64bit
- Laravel 5.4.15
- Dev env: [Laragon](https://laragon.org)
- PHP 7

#### Dusk Installation

I did the following to install dusk:

- `composer require laravel/dusk`
- Set the following in **.env**: `APP_URL=http://ticket.dev`
- Added the following to my `AppServiceProvider` `register()` method:

**app/Providers/AppServiceProviders.php**

```
use Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider;

//...

public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->environment('local', 'testing')) {
        $this->app->register(DuskServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

#### Running Dusk

When I run `php artisan dusk`, I get the following in my console:

```
1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample                                           
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: JSON decoding of remote response failed.
Error code: 4                                                                            
The response: '<!DOCTYPE html>                                                           
<html>                                                                                   
    <head>                                                                               
        <title>Laragon</title>                                                           
// the rest of the output is what http://localhost produces
```

So it appears to be hitting http://localhost and not my APP_URL?

#### Attempted solutions

I found this [github wiki page](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Work-with-proxy) and after browsing through the vendor folders related to Dusk I tried setting the proxy when the driver is set up in the `driver()` function in the file `tests/DuskTestCase.php`.

I've tried the following, but I get the same console output as mentioned before:

```
protected function driver()
{
    // same as DesiredCapabilities::chrome() except with proxy info
    $capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities([
        WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => WebDriverBrowserType::CHROME,
        WebDriverCapabilityType::PLATFORM => WebDriverPlatform::ANY,
        WebDriverCapabilityType::PROXY => [
            'proxyType' => 'manual',
            'httpProxy' => 'http://proxy:8080',
            'sslProxy' => 'http://proxy:8080',
        ],
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515',
        $capabilities,
    );

    // original code after installation
    // return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome());
}
```

and ...

```
protected function driver()
{
    $capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities([
        WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => WebDriverBrowserType::CHROME,
        WebDriverCapabilityType::PLATFORM => WebDriverPlatform::ANY,
        WebDriverCapabilityType::PROXY => [
            'proxyType' => 'manual',
            'httpProxy' => 'http://proxy:8080', // have also tried without specifying http://
            'sslProxy' => 'http://proxy:8080', // have also tried without specifying http://
        ],
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515',
        $capabilities,
        null,
        null,
        $http_proxy = 'http://proxy', // have also tried without specifying http://
        $http_proxy_port = '8080',
        null
    );
}
```

Any help on getting this working would be appreciated, thank you!